# Bind values in JSP without converting to string?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

**UPDATE**: looks like `spring:bind` does work for some collections - it might be a problem with my model, causing it not to recognise certain collections. When I've got to the bottom of this I'll update my question and/or provide an answer.

---

The `spring:bind` tag is useful for accessing values in order to print them on the page or as a form field value, e.g.

```
<spring:bind path="filename">
  <c:out value="${status.value}" />
</spring:bind>
```

`status.value` is always a String, converted using whatever PropertyEditor is detected. But this is unhelpful if I want to access a property that's a List so that I can loop over it. I can access the variable directly in JSP but then I have to know the name of the command, and I can't take advantage of things like `spring:nestedPath`.

Can `spring:bind` provide access to the actual original value rather than the converted String, or is there another tag that can do this?

I'm using Spring 3.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can access the original object by

```
${status.actualValue}
```

Comment: Thanks Peter - I was sure I'd tried using `actualValue` before and it was returning null - but now of course it works, and I can access the original List consistently.